# Cannot get info about position in liquid pool

Tags: solidity, uniswap, python, pancakeswap

I tried to get my position info in PancakeSwap liquid pool. I want to know how much token0 and token1 I added and how much uncollected fees exist.

I found this field in PancakeV3Pool contract:

```
mapping(bytes32 => Position.Info) public override positions;
```

Where bytes32 is a special key: The position's key is a hash of a preimage composed by the owner, tickLower and tickUpper.

So this is my snippet of code for encoding params and calling 'positions' function.

```
code = encode_packed(['(address,int24,int24)'], [(my_wallet_address, -55350, 54690)])

k = keccak.new(digest_bits=256)
k.update(code)
res = k.hexdigest()
print(res)

abi = getAbi('0x36696169C63e42cd08ce11f5deeBbCeBae652050')

contract = web.eth.contract(address='0x36696169C63e42cd08ce11f5deeBbCeBae652050', abi=abi)
res2 = contract.functions.positions(bytearray.fromhex(res)).call()

print(res2)
```

This code always returns [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. I tried to do it in JS code and got the same result. Hash working fine and matched with result in solidity.

Comment: have you tried calling this method directly in bscscan? (to rule out that the input arguments are wrong)

Comment: @JacoboLansac yeah, I found problem with address. I need pass PositionManager address instead of my wallet. But how can I get my personal position?

Comment: Try to paste here the `bytes32 code` you get from `encode_packed`. 
https://bscscan.com/address/0x36696169c63e42cd08ce11f5deebbcebae652050#readContract#F10
If you don't see anything still, and you are sure of the input arguments (address and tickers) perhaps you are computing wrongly the packing